# SelecedIndex of tabnavigator is appended to url

Tags: apache-flex

In my flex application when I added a tabnavigator control and ran the application, I found that a "#" was appended to the url in the browser and whenever I select one of the tabs the url changes to this "myurl#app=7049&c152-selectedIndex=1" reflecting the index of the selected tab, is this a normal behavior of the tabnavigator, is there a way of removing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a browser navigation integration related feature. You can disable it by going to project properties -> flex Compiler, and uncheck "Enable integration with browser navigation".

Bonus reference [here](http://flex.gunua.com/?p=56). You might also want to check the link at the end of that article.

Answer (score 0):

Set historyManagementEnabled property of the TabNavigator to "false"